# Kubernetes -- connect to multiple Endpoints on same NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Is there  a way for me to set up >1 pods, each listening on their TargetPort, with a single Service for all pods that serves on a specified NodePort (e.g. 30000), and connect to both endpoints of pods on the same NodePort?

I am testing on docker-desktop with 2 pods serving data. I can connect to the first pod on localholdt:30000 (NodePort on Service is 30000), but when I try to connect a second client, it hangs. I thought the Service would automatically connect the second client to the second pod's endpoint, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

My Service `describe` is:

```
Name:                     replica1-gsewz
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=cnpquery
                          app.group.com/partitionreplica=replica1
                          app.group.com/serviceMetatag=podselector1
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app.group.com/serviceMetatag=podselector1
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.98.212.171
LoadBalancer Ingress:     localhost
Port:                     http  5000/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30000/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.0.92:5000,10.1.0.93:5000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Edit:

The setup is as follows:

- pods are deployed with a server application on them. The server app listens on the pod's port 5000.
- The Service, afaik, forwards any and all requests on the node's port 30000 to the pod's port 5000
- I am on docker desktop, so I use docker's proxy to connect to port 30000 on my local machine, i.e. at http://localhost:30000
- On my local machine, I have a client machine that sends things to port 30000, and gets respones back from the pod's server.
- This setup works with a single pod (i.e I can send and receive messages on the node:30000--5000:port connection
- But when I spin up a second pod and try to connect to it on localhost:30000, it hangs

Comment: Yes generally it should work using [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) svc. However what do you mean by: `I can connect to the first pod ... when I try to connect a second client, it hangs] Please provide more information `with commands` what are you trying to do. How are you trying to connect to different pods? Are those pods managed by the same deployment? Or you are trying to spin up two distinct  pods with the same service? How did you set-up `LoadBalancer Ingress:     localhost` for svc type NodePort. It would be nice to apply yaml files

Comment: @Hanx added edit

Answer (score 0):

you can use ingress for load balancing and configure your path in the definition of ingress   in the rule section
rf
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/